# Cerrar UserControl actual al seleccionar otra opción del menú

Tags: c#

Buen día,

Tengo un formulario principal en el cual tengo un menú lateral con varios botones dependiendo el modulo al que quiera ingresar, el problema que tengo, es que si bien los UserControl se abren correctamente, al cambiar de una opción del menú a otra, y luego volver al primer formulario abierto, este se mantiene activo, es decir no se reinicia el UserControl a su estado inicial (esto es lo que quiero lograr).

Como puedo cambiar mi código para que por cada opción que seleccione, cierre el UserControl actual por completo y luego abra la nueva opción seleccionada (es decir, que solo se ejecute un UserControl a la vez)?

FORM PRINCIPAL (este es el código del boton del menu con el que abro el UserControl

```
private void ace_sindicatos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!container.Controls.Contains(uc_sindicatos.Instance))
    {
        container.Controls.Add(uc_sindicatos.Instance);
        uc_sindicatos.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        uc_sindicatos.Instance.BringToFront();
    }
    uc_sindicatos.Instance.BringToFront();
}
```

UC_SINDICATOS (acá está el código que hace publica la instancia de mi UserControl

```
public partial class uc_sindicatos : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl
{

private static uc_sindicatos _instance;

public static uc_sindicatos Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new uc_sindicatos();
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es cargarlo como si fuera la primera vez, podrías limpiar la instancia de tú clase (objeto) con Dispose() y crear una nueva instancia de tú clase.

Comment: Exactamente eso es lo que quiero hacer, es decir, si cambio de la opción A a la opción B en mi menu, quiero que esa opción A primero se cierre y no consuma más memoria y que cuando vuelva a cargar esa opción A, esté limpia como si fuera la primera vez. Me podrias ayudar con la parte del código que publique?

Comment: Ok, se a lo que te refieres, pero necesito saber como está la estructura de tú aplicación, si tienes un Contenedor padre o como está el show. Creo que lo que te está pasando es que no repintas tú VistaPadre y, por ende creas el objeto pero se queda el anterior en pantalla. 
¿Podrías poner como está la función de tú menú y como están tus componentes?